# Multithread app, runned as a service is not printing out things

Tags: python, service, subprocess, popen, systemd

I have this multithread app in python.
I start 3 threads in main.py, and one of these threads just launch feh with this function:

```
def run_feh(delay=10):
    commands = f'''export DISPLAY=:0.0 && feh --hide-pointer --fullscreen --slideshow-delay {str(delay)} &'''
    process = subprocess.Popen(commands, shell=True, cwd="folder with pics", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    return process.pid
```

The problem is that, when I run the app from a terminal, with .venv active and `python main.py`, everything works fine, and all of the print messages are working correctly.

But when I run the app as a service with systemd, I just lose control of stdout when feh starts.
I've been trying several solution (i.e. different methods from subprocess lib), but nothing seems to work.

```
[Unit]
Description=blabla
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=<myuser>
WorkingDirectory=<Path to project folder>
ExecStartPre=<some script for gpio>
ExecStart=<venv bin python> <main.py inside project folder>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm seeing logs with 'sudo journalctl -u  -f'

I know maybe it's not the best solution, but at this point i just want to know why it behaves so differently as a service.

I tried to see logs with `sudo journalctl -u <service name> -f` expecting same output as `python main.py` but all of the prints were lost after feh service was launched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.